# Transform date-format in file

Tags: regex, datetime, text, replace, gpx

I have a textfile (GPX) containing time-stamps like this

```
<time>2018-06-28-12-31-46</time>
```

But I need them to be replaced to match the ISO 8601 Format: *yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ*

As I don't really know regular expressions: Can somebody help me creating it so I can transform this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

**Find:**

```
<time>(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})</time>
```

**Replace:**

```
$1-$2-$3T$4:$5:$6Z
```

The terms you see in parentheses, e.g. the first one `(\d{4})`, are called *capture groups*.  They capture whatever matches, assuming the entire pattern matches.  Then, we may *access* those capture groups using numbers.  The first capture group may be accessed using `$1`, and so on.